# Python pandas function equivalent to Excel formula

Tags: pandas, dataframe, where-clause

I want to create a new column 'Continous Cycle count' with the python equivalent of the below excel formula The 1st row by default should contain a 0.

`=IF(AND(AD2="None",AD3="Discharge"),AF2+1,IF(AND(AD2="Discharge",AD3="Discharge"),AF2,AF2))`

AD='Batt Disch'

AF='Continous Cycle count'

MY Dataframe should look like

```
Batt Disch     Continous Cycle count
  None                0
  None                0
  Discharge           1
  Discharge           1
  None                1
  Discharge           2
  Discharge           2
```

The value in this example for this column ranges from 0 to 55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Batt Discharge': ['None', 'None','Discharge','Discharge','None','Discharge','Discharge']})

df.loc[df[df['Batt Discharge'].eq('Discharge')&df['Batt Discharge'].shift().eq('None')].index, 'Continuous Cycle count'] = 1
df['Continuous Cycle count'] = df['Continuous Cycle count'].fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
```

Result:

```
  Batt Discharge  Continuous Cycle count
0           None                       0
1           None                       0
2      Discharge                       1
3      Discharge                       1
4           None                       1
5      Discharge                       2
6      Discharge                       2
```